# very expensive remix NFT deployment

Tags: remix, gas-price, nft

I'm testing a [hello world NFT](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/create-an-nft-and-deploy-to-a-public-testnet-using-remix/6358)
deploying with remix but the transaction without anything, says is $100??

why is this so expensive?
what am I doing wrong?

here the import is the only code on the .sol

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.0/contracts/presets/ERC721PresetMinterPauserAutoId.sol";
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Deploy a contract cost transactions fees, you gas is constant but your gas price is not. Today gas was quite low between 10Gwei-20Gwei. If you want to pay less you can customize your fees on Metamask but be aware that too low gas price can make your transactions invalid if it's stay too long on mempool (and you pay transactions fees still).

It's the price to have your smart contract run on EVM and be executed by thousands of node across the world.